# How to Add data as SubCollection to all users document (in firestore Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[Class 2 Student Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqQJK.jpg)
[image: Class 1Student]

**I want to add data as subcollection to all users document at once.**
*Please Read below and see images for clarification.*
I Have `Student` collection having many document of auto generated Id. In all documents there are 3 field `Name`, `Class`, `Marks`, in which only two Student Class present - `Class 1`, `Class 2`.
I want to add `fruits` as subcollection of each Documents, where subcollection's document's field of all `Class 1` Student's should be `green fruits` having value - ***graphs*** and all Class 2 should be `red fruits` having value of ***cherry***.

all this can be done simply by adding through firebase console. But I want this should be done by clicking a button and automatics above concern done at once.

Please give appropriate Code for this query.

Answer (score 0):

First get all users, then for each add collections:

```
db.collection("Students").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        doc.ref.set({
            fruits: {apple:"green"}
        });
    });
});
```

There is a collection group query: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

that could help get collection by Mark or name

```
var museums = db.collectionGroup('landmarks').where('type', '==', 'museum');
museums.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
    });
});
```